How are unique patterns of 1s and 0s OR on and off created at GHz frequency?
How is a unique pattern of 1s and 0s representing digital data physically created at billions of bits per second? I understand that transistors turn on/off by varying voltage, but I have yet to find an answer on how unique patterns, not fixed frequencies of on/off can be generated at high speed. In other words, how is the electrical signal that is sent to a transistor able to be modulated to vary in voltage billions of times per second?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you mean by "unique patterns not fixed frequencies"? They are not interdependent parameters of a communication system.

Transistors are modulated (clocked) in the billions of times pr second (GHz) on a regular basis. Like in your phone or your desktop computer. You "just" need a clock source fast enough

For very high speed serial interfaces, a crucial block that you may find interesting to read about is the "serializer". The term "serdes" might also lead you to useful information (serializer/deserializer).

By having other transistors, also running at multi-gigahertz frequencies, generate the signal to the gate. There's a long chain of such transistors that ultimately go back to a fixed pattern of 1010101010etc, called the "clock". You can (though it's not the usual conceptual model) think of the whole system as simply modulating the clock frequency in various ways, through thousands of stages of transistors doing different things.
If you're talking specifically about such patterns as are used in communications protocols, look up "serdes"; that's the critical component in all of the highest-speed communications systems.

The rate at which a digital output is changed between high and low, is up to the designer. The maximum possible rate of up and down transitions is of course highly dependent on physical properties of the transistors involved, their layout, and their environment, but up that limit, you can "switch" them as fast as you want, at 1Hz, or at 10GHz. So this question seems to be more about how to obtain an arbitrary sequence of highs and lows, rather than how fast that sequence is presented at the output.
To produce the sequence 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 for instance, it is sufficient to initialise a group of 8 1-bit "latches" with that very data, and them have them all shift their bits to the right under control of some clock:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
There are 8 multiplexers, to control where each latch gets its data from. When LOAD is low, the multiplexers route data from the 8 data input lines 01101001, and when LOAD is high, the multiplexers route the output of each latch to the input of the next.
Each latch will store the current value at its own D input, presenting it at Q, every time the CLK signal rises from low to high. Therefore, to initialise all the latches with \$Q_0=0\$, \$Q_1=1\$, \$Q_2=1\$ etc., we first bring LOAD low, wait for CLK to rise once, then bring LOAD high again.
With LOAD high again, now each latch has its D input equal to the Q output of the stage to its left. From now on, each rising edge of CLK will cause the latches to each adopt output Q equal to its prior neighbour's current Q value, \$Q_n = Q_{n+1}\$, effectively shifting the latched data bit by bit to the right. Each CLK edge causes bits of data to appear at OUT in the sequence 0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1:



That's just one way to do it, called a "shift register". There must be dozens of variants of this design, all able to produce a stream of arbitrary bits of data, under control of some clock signal running at any rate you like, but subject to the "speed limits" of the transistor circuitry used to implement this logic.


how is the electrical signal that is sent to a transistor able to be modulated to vary in voltage billions of times per second?

The same way that it can be modulated to vary in voltage one time per second.
In other words: the principle is the same. You just need fast transistors to have the output switch fast. Whatever you do to switch a transistor once per second can be scaled down in size and up in frequency. That's how it's done.
Billions of times per second is nothing much, because that's a limitation "at the large scale". I.e. if you need to have an entire large IC working at a couple GHz, then that's all you'll get. But the individual gates in that IC can work at a much higher clock rates - as much as 100x higher in fact.
Transistors on a modern "10nm" digital CMOS process switch at time scales of picoseconds. The propagation delay (also called latency) through a small gate in a modern CPU can be under 1ps. So, if you made a little ring oscillator out of small gates, it could be well on its way to THz frequencies. The biggest problem then is how to feed the output of such an oscillator to the outside world so that it could be actually measured. The individual small gates in those tiny CMOS process nodes have very weak outputs relative to the parasitic loads imposed by anything much larger than said gates. A micron-sized speck of metal dust connected to the output of said ring oscillator can seriously slow it down already.
So, the two big problems with fast chips are:

How to get ultra-fast signals to come out of the chip without slowing everything down,

How to manage the heat dissipation caused by fast-switching CMOS transistors that not only dump a bit of heat every time they switch, but also are electrically "leaky" and act a bit like resistors between supply and ground. They are not very low resistance, but parallel billions of them and you got a problem.


Here is an excellent series of videos by Joe Smith where a single transistor oscillator is pushed towards higher and higher operating frequencies.

The fastest breadboard oscillator on the mudball, EEVBlog Contest

Digital Bandwidth Interleaving, Downconversion and Fast Oscillators

Testing a new Transistor in the Breadboard Oscillator

Fastest Breadboard Oscillator, Shaving the Transistor's leads

Conclusion to the worlds fastest breadboard oscillator



While not only used for pattern of 1s or 0s, TI’s ''low-power 45-nm RFCMOS process'' is used in devices such as the AWR1843AOP which is a Single-chip 76-GHz to 81-GHz automotive radar sensor integrating antenna on package, DSP and MCU. I.e. the device incorporates a mixture of RF, analog and digital features operating at a range of frequencies. As shown by the block diagram from the datasheet:

The TI CMOS MMIC Ready for Road – A Technology Overview white paper gives an overview of the process technology used, and has some references to IEEE conference papers.
